# Get InstallShield LE 2012 Warn About Running App

Tags: visual-studio-2012, installshield, updates

I see it all of the time when installing updates to retail applications, but after searching for two days, I have not found a way to do it.  I am trying to create a package with InstallShield LE in VS 2012.  One of my customer requests is to warn the user when the program being updated is running, and allow them to close the app (or possibly have the install try to close it).  Is there any way to do this (the simpler the better)?  Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0):

This should just happen. However you may need to make sure that you didn't remove the file and re-add it to your installation; instead make sure you update it at the source location and rebuild. (This helps ensure that the underlying component settings remain the same, which may be relevant to Windows Installer's Files-In-Use detection.)

Comment: Thank you for your reply!  I really appreciate the help.  The previous version (produced by a different developer) used a vdproj file.  We are now using VS 2012 which did away with that in favor of InstallShield LE.  I could not find an easy (and free) way to convert the vdproj, so I built the installation package from scratch.  Do you (or anyone else) know of a way to verify that the underlying component settings are unchanged in this case?

Comment: Ah, if you're creating it from scratch, rather than upgrading an existing LE project, that could explain a lot. Did you try importing the Visual Studio project into LE?

Comment: No.  I am not sure how to go about doing that, and most of what I read when I was looking it up said not to do it.  Is there an easy way of importing a vdproj into LE (that would be awesome!)?